# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, image-uploading, intervention

I'm trying to build an upload image class, i pass the file and the route and it upload the image this is the code

this is the form

```
<form class="new-user-form row" method="POST" action="{{ URL::to('administrador/producto/nuevo/enviar') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="img[]">
</form>
```

it sended to the controller

```
$file = Input::file();
    foreach($file['img'] as $f)
    {
        $img = new ItemImage;
        $img->item_id = $id;
        /*if i return $f->getClientOriginalName() here it return the name of
        the file without error.
        if i return var_dump($f) here it will show the response below.
        */
        $img->image   = ImageManager::upload_image($f,'images/items'); 
        $img->save();
    }
```

the class look like this

```
<?php
Class ImageManager
{
    function __construct() {
    }

    public static function upload_image(&$file, $path)
    {
        $ruta    = $path;
        //if i return $file in here it return the tmp path
        //if i return var_dump($file) here it return the response below
        $extension = File::extension($file->getClientOriginalName());//<-this line trow the error

        $time = time();
        $miImg = $time.'.'.$extension;
        while (file_exists($ruta.$miImg)) {
            $time = time();
            $miImg = $time.'.'.$extension;
        }
        $file->move($ruta,$miImg);
        return $miImg;
    }
}
```

when i call the uploader code in the `foreach` it works, but when i call it from the class the error its triggered.

if i use the code inse a function on the controller it work, but i need to call globally the function, i'm using `intervention/image` to manipulate the images.

why does this happend? and how can i fix it?

---

**EDITE**

in both cases, in the controller and the custom class i made, when i var_dump the `file` it show this response

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) {
  ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(6) "l2.jpg"
  ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
  ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(10737)
  ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php782D.tmp"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(11) "php782D.tmp"
}
```

if it is an `UploadedFile` instance why trow the error, and why cant use the function on my custom class?

Comment: I don't understand. You call `ImageController::upload_image`, but you show us `Class ImageManager`. You also say you are using `Interevention/Image`, but I don't see any reference to `Image` anywhere. I also don't see you passing a file by reference anywhere!

Comment: sorry about that, the name of the class is ImageManager, about the intervention, i use it to resize the image, i delete the code but the error persist.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace, that should contain the file names and lines where the error is being triggered. Also post that code, if it's not present on the answer.